# wait for functiion to complete and execute a function (page loading) that waits for the prevoius function completion

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can I do this in my function: while Post() is working I want to display a loading sign.

```
function Post() {

    // 1. Create XHR instance - Start
    var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
    }
    // 1. Create XHR instance - End

    // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                document.getElementById('new_story_post').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start

    var textid = document.getElementById("textid").value;

    // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - Start 
    xhr.open('POST', 'post.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("textid=" + textid);
    // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - End
}
```

Comment: Since you rolled-back my edit, can you improve the formatting of your question and fix typos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it in your code already. Please check the documentation about the [onreadystatechange event](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp).

The onreadystatechange event is triggered every time the readyState changes. The readyState property holds the status of the XMLHttpRequest.

Hope this helps.

Edit: [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/4hHUC/)

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

        $("#loading").append('Loaded. Status is ' + xmlhttp.readyState + '<br />');

    } else {

        $("#loading").append('Working... Status is ' + xmlhttp.readyState + '<br />');
    }
}
```

Comment: can u tell me how do i use 
         if (xhr.readyState == 3) in my code

Answer (score 1):

### Algorithm

- Display a loading sign before invoking your service.
- Hide it when the service has responded.

### Implementation

Update your function:

```
function Post() {
  // 0. Display the loading sign
  document.getElementById("loading-overlay").style.display = "block";

  // 1. Create XHR instance
  // ...

  // 2. Response handler 
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
        document.getElementById('new_story_post').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
      }

      // Hide the loading sign whatever the response is
      document.getElementById("loading-overlay").style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

Append the loading sign to the `body`:

```
<div id="loading-overlay">Loading...</div>
```

Add some CSS:

```
#loading-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

### Bonus

You could use a callback to better decouple your code.

```
function Post(textid, fn) {
  // 1. Create XHR instance - Start
  var xhr;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } else {
    return fn(new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser"));
  }
  // 1. Create XHR instance - End

  // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
        fn(null, xhr.responseText);
      } else {
        fn(new Error('Request failed'));
      }
    }
  };

  // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - Start 
  xhr.open('POST', 'post.php');
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send("textid=" + textid);
  // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - End
}
```

Usage:

```
// Display the loader
document.getElementById("loading-overlay").style.display = "block";

// Get the textid
var textid = document.getElementById("textid").value;

// Call the service
Post(textid, function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
  } else {
    // Hide loader
    document.getElementById("loading-overlay").style.display = "none";

    // Update view
    document.getElementById('new_story_post').innerHTML = res;
  }
});
```